# Multi-module project in maven

Tags: maven-2

I have some multi-module project. 
Some modules are packaged as wars and some as jars.

When I start from the root module : `mvn war:exploded` I thought it would apply the step only  to the war projects. But it tries to apply the `mvn war:exploded` on all the projects which obviously fails (no web.xml and so on).

Any ideas how can I tell maven to apply in only to the war packaging modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running `war:war` (which is the goal bound to `package` for a project with a war packaging), the war plugin automatically creates a directory of the exploded war file first and then compresses it into the actual war file. So why don't you simply run `mvn package` during your reactor build?

If really this is not an option, you could maybe use one of maven's [advanced reactor options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/), and more precisely:

> **-pl, --projects**
>          Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects

and list only the war modules.